# Can the static keyword in C be used to improve performance?

Tags: c, static

is there a performance difference between doing something like:

```
void function() {
char bufgfer[256];
// ...
}
```

and

```
void function() {
static char bufgfer[256];
// ...
}
```

I know it changed the way the function will work, but how about the performance? is the second one faster?

hanks

Comment: theoritically yes, as the buffer will probably be allocated only once but the first one is just a subtraction on the stack only being really notice if this function is called a lot of times.

Comment: It might be sometimes, and sometimes it might be slower, it depends on other variables in the function, and what does is access.

Comment: @RedX - this is not that accurate. allocation on the stack may be a simple change to the stack pointer, and if there are other variables, it may be done in the same change. if you have some variables on the stack and one static variable the difference in their location may decrease performance.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet You are right, and i knew that. Maybe i should have phrased my comment more appropriately. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The relevant performance difference becomes apparent when the version using a static buffer stops performing when multiple threads run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is probably faster if the buffer ends up in a cache near the CPU.

If you thought that the first one was slower because the buffer would somehow be allocated at run time, then, no, this is not the reason. All this is handled by the compiler at compile time. Moreover, making the buffer static will probably keep it out of the cache. (But who knows, or cares?)

It seems to me that you're considering premature optimizations.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for: I thought that it would be faster to not have to create the buffer on the stack for each function call, apparently I was wrong

Answer (score 3):

Never choose the storage duration (static vs automatic) of an object based on performance. Storage durations do not exist for performance purposes but because they have seriously different semantics; making the buffer static will horribly break lots of potential uses of your code, most obviously multi-threaded use. The only time an object should have static storage duration is when it's storing a long-term global state that needs to persist between invocations, and even then it's usually a design mistake (this state should be kept in a context held by the caller).

With that said, performance is unlikely to be better with static storage duration, and in many cases (especially PIC shared libraries or PIE executables) accessing a static variable will be slower than accessing an auto one, because the function must load the GOT register (if it's not already loaded) and do GOT-indirect or GOT-relative addressing.

Answer (score 2):

It might be sometimes, and sometimes it might be slower, it depends on other variables in the function, and what does is access.

The most important thing is using it when needed, and not in terms of optimizations, but in term of functionality. If you don't need a variable to be static, it shouldn't be, the implications on different platforms are irrelevant most of the time.